# Dice score and accuracy are the same in multi-class image segmentation with Keras and TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, image-segmentation

I am working on a multi-class image segmentation problem using Keras and TensorFlow, and I am using the Dice coefficient as my evaluation metric. However, when I compare the Dice coefficient to the accuracy, I am finding that they have the same value. I have implemented the dice_coef_multiClass function shown below, which computes the Dice coefficient for multiple classes:

```
def dice_coef_multiClass(y_true, y_pred, num_classes=31, smooth=1):
 y_true = K.cast(y_true, dtype='int32')
 y_pred = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
 y_true = K.cast(K.one_hot(y_true, num_classes), "int32")
 y_pred = K.cast(K.one_hot(y_pred, num_classes), "int32")

 axis = [1, 2, 3]
 intersection = K.cast(K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=axis), "float32")
 union = K.cast(K.sum(y_true + y_pred, axis=axis), "float32")

 dice = K.mean((2. * intersection + smooth) / (union + smooth), axis=0)

 return dice

OPTIMIZER = Adam(lr=1e-3)

model.compile(optimizer=OPTIMIZER, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
           metrics=[dice_coef_multiClass, 'accuracy'])

steps_per_epoch = 2678//batch_size
validation_steps = 400//batch_size

history = model.fit(
training_dataset, 
epochs=EPOCHS, 
steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
verbose=2, shuffle=True,
validation_data=validation_dataset,
validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

I call this function with my test data and compute the average Dice coefficient and accuracy across all classes. However, I am finding that the Dice coefficient and accuracy have the same value.

Can someone explain why the Dice coefficient and accuracy are the same in this case, even though they are supposed to be different measures of performance? Is there something wrong with my implementation of the dice_coef_multiClass function?
the y_pred is 8x256x256x31 (classes)
I doing a semgnetaiton int he cityScape

Dice coefficient = (2 * TP) / (TP + FP + FN)